# Proving continuinty of scalar product of two continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$Suppose~f,g~:~\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}~are~both~continuous~at~p~\epsilon~ \mathbb{R}^{n}.~Show~that~the~scalar~product~f\cdot g~:~\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}~is~continuous~at~p.$

I'm not sure whether this can be proven the same way as for products of functions in $\mathbb{R}$. I'm assuming not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a $f=(f_1,f_2,...,f_k)$ and $g=(g_1,g_2,...,g_k)$ are continuous if and only if each component function  $g_i,f_i$ is continuous

Thus $f \cdot g=\sum_{i=1}^kf_ig_i$ is continuous a finite sum of product of real valued continuous functions,since each $f_i,g_i:\Bbb{R^n} \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The inner product is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^k\times \mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}$ (why?). You can write your function as a composition of some functions with this one.